# F# Set.union argument order performance

Tags: f#

Is there any recommended way to call a Set.union if I know one of the two sets will be larger than the other?

```
Set.union large small
```

or

```
Set.union small large
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, sets are represented as ballanced tree (you can [check the source online](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/set.fs)). When calculating the union of sets, the algorithm splits the smaller set (tree) based on the value from the root of the larger set (tree) into a set of smaller and a set of larger elements. The splitting is always performed on the smaller set to do less work. Then it recursively unions the two left and right subsets and performs some re-ballancing.

**The summary is**, the algorithm does not really depend on which of the sets is the first and which of them is the second argument. It will always choose the better option depending on the size of set (which is stored as part of the data structure).

Comment: "The splitting is always performed on the smaller set to do less work". FWIW, OCaml's Set.union splits the larger set and is much faster than F#. In fact, computing the union of non-overlapping sets in O(log n) in OCaml and O(n) in F# because of this.

Answer (score 2):

The intent behind your question seems to improve performance when using `Set.union` by exploiting undocumented features of this function implementation. But `Set.union` abstracts you from implementation complexity leaving just set-theoretic meaning of **union** operation that is **agnostic** to the argument properties. Purposedly breaking through this abstraction layer adversely affects complexity and maintainability of your code and should be avoided.

Although sometimes you have no choice but deal with [leaky abstractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction), `Set.union` is definitely not the case. And it is good to [hear from Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692130/f-set-union-argument-order-performance/7692670#7692670) that `Set.union` implementation does not have leaky abstraction flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you want. You can also do `small + large`, and `large - small` for difference (of course also `small - large`).